# Resizing 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-resizing, spyder, scatter3d

I managed to plot a 3D graph using Spyder (Python 3.5). However, the size of the graph is too small. How do I increase the size of the graph so that I can save it as an image file?

The below is the code used to plot the graph:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x =[0,1,2,3,4]
y =[11,1,5,2,9]
z =[1,2,3,4,5,6]



ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('Days since last interaction')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of conversions')
ax.set_zlabel('Total number of interactions')

plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the named argument `figsize` when creating your figure

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
y =[11, 1, 5, 2, 9, 0]
z =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  # this array contained one value too many. (I padded the other two arrays)

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('Days since last interaction')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of conversions')
ax.set_zlabel('Total number of interactions')

plt.show()
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much for your help Reblochon!